# Загрузка динамического массива структур из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, динамические-массивы, динамические-структуры

Помогите найти ошибки. Есть динамический массив структур(CARD). Нужно загрузить из файла массив структур.

То что у меня получилось:

```
void downloadFile()
    {
    xcard = new CARD[n + 1];
    char file[L];
    cout << "Введите название файла. \n";
    cin >> file;
    ifstream fin(file);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        if (xcard == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Нет памяти \n";
            _getch();
            n = 0;//Количество строк уже имеющихся строк в массиве структур
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            fin >> xcard[i].surname >> xcard[i].init;
            fin >> xcard[i].surname >> xcard[i].init;
            strcat_s(xcard[i].surname, " ");
            strcat_s(xcard[i].surname, xcard[i].init);
            fin >> xcard[i].pole.pointofdeparture >> xcard[i].pole.arrivalpoint >> xcard[i].pole.trainnumber >> xcard[i].time.hours >> xcard[i].time.minutes >> xcard[i].type >> xcard[i].cost;
            xcard[n+1] = xcard[i];
            n++;
            cout << "База данных загружена" << endl;
            _getch();
            return;
        }

        }
        else 
        {
            cout << file << "Файл не открылся. \n";
            _getch;
            delete[] xcard;
            n = 0;
            xcard = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном коде есть куча ошибок. А часть не видна, так как код приведен не полностью.

Создаете

```
xcard = new CARD[n + 1];
```

А потом проверяете

```
if (xcard == NULL)
```

С очень большой вероятностью, это условие никогда не отработает. Оно сработает только если у Вас очень древний компилятор (очень очень) или сознательно поменятли настройки компилятора/линковщика. Если память не удается выделить, new бросает исключение.

В любом случае, лучше использовать просто вектор - тогда память будет автоматом подчищаться.

```
fin >> xcard[i].surname >> xcard[i].init;
fin >> xcard[i].surname >> xcard[i].init;
```

Здесь дважды вводятся одни и те же данные. Скорее всего копипаста

```
strcat_s(xcard[i].surname, " ");
strcat_s(xcard[i].surname, xcard[i].init);
```

surname и inin у вас `char[..]` ? Почему не обычный string? К тому же, у этой функции [три аргумента](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d45bbxx4.aspx) (средний - это будет размер)

```
xcard[n+1] = xcard[i];
n++;
```

А здесь гарантированно пишем за пределы массива. Так как структура CARD не известна, то наверно ещё и копируется не совсем так, как ожидается.

Дальше, так как xcard в случае успешного завершения никуда не передается, то будет ещё и утечка памяти.

И на последок, это страшная сместь с и с++. Код на чистом с++ был бы в раза два меньше (и понятнее).

Comment: surname и init, да char, так требуется по лабе. Исправил что было. n - количество уже имеющихся строк в массиве. По прежнему не работает.